# Can you run Ruby and Rails and PHP together on the same site?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

Why? Because for our site I want to develop a Rails application, but I also want a separate part of it (perhaps the public directory) to be easy to modify by a PHP programmer/web designer.

Is it possible to run both on the same site? Are there any reasons why it is not a good idea or not a best practice?

Comment: no problem here, I usually do that to have website + custom wordpress

Comment: as long as you keep the developers on separate sites, you shouldnt have a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure Nginx and Lighttpd can do it.  For example, you can run php worker processes with php-fpm and configure the webserver to send any php jobs to them.  Every other job could be configured for rails.  I have never tried it myself.

You can use the vhost, port, or file extension (*.php) to determine where the webserver will send the request.

I think it would be an ok idea if lets say you have a PHP site but want to have a non-blocking application in nodeJS or use Tornado and have Nginx configured to proxy requests to them.

Example where Nginx is used for PHP-FPM and Node.js

http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/04/nginx-php-fpm-and-node-js-install-on-centos-5-5/

In this example Node is ran on port 8000